# download all tracks from current_cart line_items in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `Rails 4.0.0` and `Ruby 2.0.0`

My app is for downloading mp3 files from s3 storage. Downloading a single mp3 track works, however downloading all selected tracks in current_cart is not working.

my controller is
tracks_controller.rb

```
def mp3_download_all
  if !current_cart.line_items.blank?
    current_cart.line_items.each_with_index do |track,i|
      puts track.track.inspect
      track.track.increment! :download_count
      send_file(Paperclip.io_adapters.for(track.track.mp3_track_file).path, :type => track.track.mp3_track_file_content_type, :disposition => "attachment", :filename => track.track.mp3_track_file_file_name)
    end
  end
end
```

It's downloading only the last track.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this server side - one http request results in one response, i.e one file (to my knowledge browsers don't consistently support multipart mime responses).

Your best bet is probably to create a zip containing all the files and send that (the rubyzip gem makes this very easy). You might want to do this in some sort of background job (delayed_job, sidekiq etc)